Sobolev functions don't "jump"
let's consider a Ball $B_r \subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and a Sobolev function $u\in W^{2,2}(B_r(0))$. I would like to find a formal argument why the weak first order derivative $|\nabla u|$ cannot "jump", as $\nabla u$ itself is again weakly differentiable, due to $u\in W^{2,2}(B_r(0))$. Assume that for one $i\in\{1,2,...,n\}$ the measure information
$$\mathcal{L}^n(\big\{ x\in B_r(0): \textstyle{\frac{1}{2}} \leq \partial_{x_i} u(x) \leq 1 \big\}) =0$$
is at our disposal. I have to conclude that there either holds $\partial_{x_i} u(x) \leq \frac{1}{2}$ almost everywhere on $B_r(0)$ or there holds $\partial_{x_i} u(x) \geq 1$ almost everywhere on $B_r(0)$, i.e. exclude jumps of the form where for example $\partial_{x_i} u(x) \leq \frac{1}{2}$ almost everywhere on $B_{\frac{r}{2}}(0)$ and $\partial_{x_i} u(x)\geq 1$ almost everywhere on $B_r(0)\setminus B_{\frac{r}{2}}(0)$. I am thankful for any help!

Note: This answer is partial, in that I only give a complete proof for when $n=2$.
An example of a jump
In general, the lack of jumps arises due to the weak differentiability. For a concrete example consider $u(x) = \chi_{B_{r/2}}(0)$ which is the characteristic function on $B_{r/2}(0)$. Then for a test function $\varphi \in C^{\infty}_c(B_r(0))$ we have
\begin{equation}
  \int_{B_r(0)} u(x) \nabla \varphi(x) \,\mathrm{d}x = \int_{B_{r/2}(0)} \nabla\varphi(x) = \int_{\partial B_{r/2}(0)} \varphi(x) \frac{x}{\lvert x \rvert} \,\mathrm{d}\mathcal{H}^{n-1}(x),
\end{equation}
where $\mathcal{H}^{n-1}$ is the $(n-1)$-Hausdorff measure.
Then there does not exist $V \in L^1(B_r(0);\mathbb R^n)$ such that
\begin{equation}
  \int_{B_r(0)} u(x) \nabla\varphi(x) \,\mathrm{d}x = - \int_{B_r(0)} V(x) \varphi(x) \,\mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}
holds for all test functions $\varphi \in C^{\infty}_c(B_r(0))$.
In general, functions with jump discontinuities along $(n-1)$-dimensional surfaces are said to be of bounded variation, and their distributional derivative can be understood in terms of measures.
The general question you pose is more complicated however, because a-priori the "jump" may occur over a level sets which are highly irregular, and so we cannot integrate by parts like I did in the above example.

General case
It suffices to consider $v = \partial_{x_i}u$, which is weakly differentiable (and in fact $W^{1,2}$ and we will work with the precise representative of $v$ in what follows.
Moreover, we will consider the domain is the unit cube $Q = (0,1)^n$ for simplicity; the general case follows by considering sub-cubes $Q(a,\varepsilon) \Subset B_r(0)$.
Define the sets
\begin{align}
  A &= \{ x \in Q : v(x) < 1/2 \}, \\
  B &= \{ x \in Q : v(x) > 1 \},
\end{align}
so by assumption $\mathcal L^n(Q \setminus (A \cup B)) = 0$.
We will use the fact that Sobolev functions are absolutely continuous along almost all lines; see for instance Theorem 4.20 in
Evans, Lawrence Craig; Gariepy, Ronald F., Measure theory and fine properties of functions, Textbooks in Mathematics. Boca Raton, FL: CRC Press (ISBN 978-1-4822-4238-6/hbk). 309 p. (2015). ZBL1310.28001.
To state the quoted result, for each $1 \leq i \leq n$ define
\begin{equation}
  H_{i} = \{ x \in \mathbb R^n : x_i = 0 \}.
\end{equation}
Then for $\mathcal H^{n-1}$-almost all $x \in H_{i} \cap Q$ we have
\begin{equation}
  t \mapsto v(x + te_i)
\end{equation}
is absolutely continuous on the interval $(0,1)$.
Then if we define the sets
\begin{align}
  A_{i, x} &= \{ t \in (0,1) : v( x + te_i) < 1/2\}, \\
  B_{i, x} &= \{ t \in (0,1) : v( x + te_i) > 1\},
\end{align}
for all $1 \leq i \leq n$ and almost all $x \in H_{i} \cap Q$, since $t \mapsto v( x + te_i)$ is absolutely continuous on $(0,1)$, it follows that either
\begin{equation}
  \mathcal L^1(A_{i, x}) = 0 \quad\text{or}\quad \mathcal L^1(B_{i, x}) = 0,
\end{equation}
so either $A_{i, x}$ or $B_{i,x}$ is the full interval $(0,1)$.
Without loss of generality assume that $\mathcal L^1(A) > 0$.
Then it should follow that $\mathcal L^n(Q \setminus A)=0$ by showing that $A_{i,x}$ is the full interval for almost all $x$ and all $1 \leq i \leq n$. However this seems relatively technical, so I will only consider...

The case $n=2$: By Fubini's theorem we have
\begin{equation}
  \mathcal L^2(A) = \int_{H_1 \cap Q} \mathcal L^1(A_{1,(0,x_2)}) \,\mathrm{d} \mathcal H^{1}(0,x_2) > 0.
\end{equation}
Then there is some $S \subset (s,t)$ such that $\mathcal L^1(A_{1,(0,x_2)}) > 0$ for all $x_2 \in S$ hence by the above, we have $A_{1,x}$ is the entire interval $(0,1)$ for all $x \in S$.
That is, we have
\begin{equation}
  (0,1) \times S \subset A.
\end{equation}
Then for almost all $x_1 \in (0,1)$ we have
\begin{equation}
  \mathcal L^1(A_{2,(x_1,0)}) \geq \mathcal L^1(S) > 0,
\end{equation}
so it follows that $S \supset A_{2,(x_1,0)} = (0,1)$, and hence that $\mathcal L^2(Q \setminus A) = 0$.

I will leave the case of general $n$. I believe one can induct on the dimension $n$, and the essence is captured in the $n=2$ case already, but I don't see how to write this concisely at the moment.

Thanks a lot for your answer! I am seriously surprised that such a, let's call it "fundamental", property of Sobolev functions is nowhere to be found in the literature!

Edit: I also thought about approximating $u$ resp. $\nabla u$ by using standard mollifiers or the Meyers-Serrin theorem, but I am not sure whether this approach leads to anything or not.
